# simplify a query that applies a condition on every columns

Tags: sql

I have a table and I want to write a query that filters the rows that all the columns are null. Is there any way in SQL to write it more simple instead of naming all the columns?
here is my query so far:

```
Select d
From database d
Where d.c1 is null
and d.c2 is null
and d.c3 is null
and d.c4 is null
and d.c5 is null
and d.c6 is null
```

Comment: No. There are various ways you can construct the query but regardless if you need to test a column you need to specify it by name somewhere. You might try a computed/calculated column which can simplify your query but the computed/calculated column will still have to reference the columns by name.

Comment: you could write `Select d
From database d
Where COALESCE(d.c1,d.c2, d.c3,d.c4, d.c5, d.c6) is null` but ni you need towrite all columns down